# google analytics for youtube

Tags: google-analytics, youtube, google-tag-manager

I have embed youtube videos on my web site and want to track in google analytics video events. I set up Youtube tag in Google Tag Manager and install Google Tag Manager on my web site. I see Google Tag Manager debugger on my web site and [fired tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yheq6.png). [Tag details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EnpQ.png). But I don't see Youtube in Google Analytics. I am not sure what is wrong - my installation or I look at events in a wrong place.

Additionally in Chrome console I see [a command executed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hej6w.png).

What is a little bit confusing for me is tracking ids. Google Analytics shows [UA-XXX77-7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8oCw.png), while fired video tag has UA-XXX77-9 (as shown in the tag details before). But maybe everything is okay with this.

Comment: You're sending video hits to UA-XXX77-9 property but you're looking for them in UA-XXX77-7 ... and obviously you do not see them.
Change the target Property ID in the analytics tags in the Tag Manager.

Comment: Can't find the appropriate setting for this. Could you advise where it is https://www.dropbox.com/s/e2fyka65adndqgu/gtm.png?dl=0?

Comment: I found it and it works, thanks a lot for you help.

Comment: Good! Mark my comment as useful if it was for you, please.